# Use of the Pearl of Power?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, magic

Can an arcane trickster rogue use a Pearl of Power in D&D 5e? The explanation of which classes can use a pearl of power does not include rogues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes

In order to attune to a pearl of power, you must be a spellcaster. An arcane trickster rogue can cast spells, so they count. So would a drow barbarian. Any spellcaster works.

> Requires attunement by a spellcaster

[The Dungeon Master's Guide errata](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwje8c6QqanaAhVIylMKHVuiDBgQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2KrzmUVBPFuQEtzh76SUCG) changed the text in the Attunement section to specify this. New printings have this on page 136.

> If the prerequisite is to be a spellcaster, a creature qualifies if it can cast at least one spell using its traits or features